# I'm getting the following error in the log upon creating a new project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting these errors in the log when I create a new project. In order to fix it I already have tried:

- updating android studio to the latest version
- updating the gradle
- clicking on the solution provided in the log does not do anything

what can I do? here is a screen shot

[image]

Comment: What's your gradle version

Comment: What issues a dependencies refresh?

Comment: @TimCastelijns 2.4

Comment: @Amesys I don't understand your question

Comment: @TimCastelijns sorry its 2.10

Comment: Gradle, not the wrapper. Whats behind the colon for you? `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:`

Comment: @TimCastelijns this must be it:  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

Comment: Yes ok that seems right.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was fixed by renaming the .gradle file which is located somewhere inside C:\user\